# Book on Linux OS design?

Tags: linux

What is a good book about why linux has been designed the way it has? Such as why are HDs in `/dev/sda`, why `/dev/` null, zero, urandom and such are files (or pipes). Why do we have loopback device (I see 0-7 and control on my linux distro), why we have bin, sbin, lib and usr (and the difference between them). Everything about `/proc`. What is inside of the kernel and what isn't? From my memory init.d isn't part of the kernel and I was unsure how an program would be executed and know when to run these. What are block and character device represented as files? and why couldn't a character device be a '1 byte' (or int) block device?

I have no idea why everything is a file (including sockets) and what happens when I write `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. Is that a named pipe to the OS which reads the CPU info on the fly and generate that text each time I call it?

Comment: Good question. I would like to know more from the answers :)

Comment: Per http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2642/41104 I'm voting to close this.

Comment: Major readers here should read [Just for Fun](http://www.amazon.com/Just-Fun-Story-Accidental-Revolutionary/dp/0066620732/) and [The Cathedral & The Bazaar](http://www.amazon.com/Cathedral-Bazaar-Musings-Accidental-Revolutionary/dp/0596001088/) first.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two good online resources that throws light on design of Unix-like OSes:

[The Design and Implementation of the 4.4BSD Operating System](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/design-44bsd/book.html)

[The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/index.html)

[Understanding the linux kernel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596005652) and [Linux Kernel Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672329468) are good books to understand the kernel internals.

The classic [UNIX Programming Environment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013937681X) is a great book that describes design philosophies of UNIX systems along with their practical usage.

This 7-part [frequently asked questions](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part1) is also a useful resource to understand Unix in general.

Comment: This looks great. Do you recommend reading them in a specific order? which should be the first 2 or 3 I read? (I think I may read all of them). I see history of in your second link so I suspect I should read the first two first (I guess the order you linked) maybe the 7 part FAQ then the two kernel links then finally the environment? Maybe its not a great idea to go in that order but that sounds like a good order to me at this moment. Maybe i'll do the 7 part FAQ first since faqs are normally short?

Comment: I'd suggest start with the classic, then 7 part FAQ, then the Art of UNIX Programming.